# How to edit INC with latest library in perl

Tags: perl

How can I avoid the error below when running a Perl script?

```
Can't locate YAML/XS.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ../../../YAML-LibYAML-0.35/blib/lib/YAML/XS.pm /app/utp/utp/apps_oper/perl5lib ../../../3rdparty/YAML-LibYAML-0.35/blib/lib ../../../3rdparty/YAML-LibYAML-0.35/blib/arch ../../../perl ../../adhoc/perl ../../api/perl ../../3rdparty/YAML-LibYAML-0.35/blib/lib ../../3rdparty/YAML-LibYAML-0.35/blib/arch ./common ../../adhoc/perl ../../api/perl ../../../3rdparty/YAML-LibYAML-0.35/blib/lib ../../../3rdparty/YAML-LibYAML-0.35/blib/arch ./common ../../adhoc/perl ../../api/perl /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at common/FixMessageData.pm line 32.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at common/FixMessageData.pm line 32.
Compilation failed in require at common/OrderGenSessionFact.pm line 32.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at common/OrderGenSessionFact.pm line 32.
Compilation failed in require at OrderGenSessionClient.pl line 21.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at OrderGenSessionClient.pl line 21.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing `YAML/XS.pm` is part of the package `libyaml-libyaml-perl`.

Therefore install via:

```
 sudo apt-get install libyaml-libyaml-perl
```

---

Why do I know that?

```
% apt-file search YAML/XS.pm
libyaml-libyaml-perl: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/YAML/XS.pm
```

Comment: After I installed it... It says can't locate loadable object for the module YAML::XS::LibYAML

Comment: Sorry, but this should be a new question. Comments are for clarification and not for new questions. :)